# Mysql skips single quote, no error

Tags: php, mysql

iam having an issue with a single quote
I have a form with a select dropdown and multiple options.

```
$TMPL['category'] = htmlspecialchars($TMPL['category'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

foreach ($CONF['categories'] as $cat => $skin) {
  $cat = htmlspecialchars($cat, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

  if ($TMPL['category'] == $cat) {
    $TMPL['categories_menu'] .= "<option value=\"{$cat}\" selected=\"selected\">{$cat}</option>\n";
  }
  else {
    $TMPL['categories_menu'] .= "<option value=\"{$cat}\">{$cat}</option>\n";
  }
}
```

Now i submit this as usual, "cat" may contain a single quote

I have it escaped using mysql escape function ( yes this also checks for magic_quotes ) in my form process function

```
$TMPL['category'] = $DB->escape($FORM['category'], 1);
```

If i echo out this variable all is good, so single quote is escaped, and you would think mysql will update my row.
Html, php, db are also in utf8

Totally lost, maybe i just dont see my mistake, but it works everywhere else, with inputs all is good, but as soon as a single quote is in a select box, mysql simply skips it altogether and also dont produce any error

```
$DB->query("UPDATE `my_table` SET `category` = '{$TMPL['category']}' WHERE `xx` = 'xx'", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Note, the above query is not complete regarding columns, i removed all other for readability. The other fields still get updated if i have selected a single quote option value. And when the option does not contain a single quote it also works.

I Hope someone can give me some insight, sick of looking at the code, as it appears totally correct

Thank you

**Update 1**

A bit more insight, i have 3 select options

```
<option value="category1"></option>
<option value="category'bla"></option>
<option value="category3"></option>
```

Now when i submit the form and have the second option choosen, it skips and submit the third instead ( always the last in the list ), although when i echo the choosen post var $TMPL['category'] in my submit function, it is correct. But in the Update query it is different ( Did not defined it multiple times )

**Update 2**
Ok , i really dont know why, but as descriped above, i make a $TMPL['category'] out of the posted form value and escape it, then use it in the query.
That does not work

```
$TMPL['category'] = $DB->escape($FORM['category'], 1);
```

If i add

```
$any_var = $TMPL['category'];
```

below it and use $any_var in the query it suddenly works, dont understand

Comment: can you assign your query statement to a variable and then echo that variable so that you can see how is the query statement getting rendered?

Comment: Is the single quote pair inside your $TMPL causing an error? What happens if you change it to this `$DB->query("UPDATE `my_table` SET `category` = '{$TMPL["category"]}' WHERE `xx` = 'xx'", __FILE__, __LINE__);` --NB double quotes used.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Yes, i already did that. My word of skipping might not have been the best. What happens in the query is, that as soon as we try to submit a single quote value, the `category` = 'xx' doesnt hold the new value, but the the next option value. Its as if the $FORM['cat'] skips to the next option

Comment: @ChrisL Nope doesnt change anything, the same works works with inputs, but not selectbox.

Comment: Are you sure that it is sending the last entry. If your select allows multiple selction, then your $_POST['dropdown_field'] will send an array to the backend.

Comment: @crafter It does not allow multiple section, i have multiple options the user can choose from. I select option 2, echo the post var in my submit handler, and its correct. But the query still submits the last option found in that select box, although it is the same post var in the update query. And the update query also comes directly after the escape, so iam not overwriting the post var or something

Answer (score 0):

1) Echo out the the query to see how it is rendered.

2) Try escaping the quote yourself. Sometimes you find a promising escape or unescape function that is actually built for escaping more than what you bargained for.

Comment: Please see my edit at the end of the question for a hopefully more explaining situation, as well as my other comments, already tried all that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. Problem has been spotted. It was another validating function which checked if the post value match any of the allowed ones.
And since $TMPL['category'] was escaped and none of the validation vars ( if tmpl var == allowed var )
It overwrote my variable with the last of the validation loop, since it wasnt finding any match

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: @eis indeed, but that was the issue, totally forgot i had such an function

Comment: @aris There is this function to answer your own question, hence it has been used. Thanks for that unneeded comment.